# How do I hide the select tag based on Js iteration of a list

Tags: javascript

I had a challenge getting this question but tried to research and redo it.
I'm trying to get an item in a list from a controller, then iterate through the list. Based on the content of the array, I would like to show or hide the select that has options in it. I can't seem to hide or show any of them at the moment.

```js
var names = ['marketing']; //or ['business']
var text = "";
var i;
//$(document).ready(function() {
for (i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
  if (names[i] === 'business') {
    //alert('Hooray'); 
    $("#business").show("slow");
    $(".marketing").hide("fast");
  } else
  if (names[i] === 'marketing') {
    $("#marketing").show("slow");
    $(".marketing").hide("fast");

  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="all" id="note">
  Some content will be posted here...
</div>
<select id="marketing" multiple>
  <option value="1">Definition</option>
  <option value="2">Advertise</option>
  <option value="3">Promotion</option>
</select>


<select id="business" multiple>
  <option value="1">Definition</option>
  <option value="2">Buy</option>
  <option value="3">Sell</option>
</select>
```

Comment: assuming you hide the `<select>` elements with CSS (which you forgot to add to the question) your code works fine

Comment: Thank you so much... Just what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `array` contains the exact name of the `id` you can "hide" the elements with CSS and show them with two lines of javascript

```js
var names = ['marketing'];//or ['business']
names.forEach( name => {
  $('#' + name).show('slow')
});
```

```css
select {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="all" id="note">
    Some content will be posted here...
</div>
<select id="marketing" multiple>
  <option value="1">Definition</option>
  <option value="2">Advertise</option>
  <option value="3">Promotion</option>
</select> 


<select id="business" multiple>
  <option value="1">Definition</option>
  <option value="2">Buy</option>
  <option value="3">Sell</option>
</select>
```